# How to download csv in python when the link is not directly linked to the csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to download the economic calendar events on myfxbook.com.
They have an option to download the calendar in a csv and an example of the url is as such:
https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?filter=0-1-2-3_ANG-ARS-AUD-BRL-CAD-CHF-CLP-CNY-COP-CZK-DKK-EEK-EUR-GBP-HKD-HUF-IDR-INR-ISK-JPY-KPW-KRW-MXN-NOK-NZD-PEI-PLN-QAR-ROL-RUB-SEK-SGD-TRY-USD-ZAR&end=2021-08-20%2015:59:59.059&start=2021-08-18%2016:00:00.0&calPeriod=10

[image: MyFxBook Calendar]

I'm aware that this is not an explicit csv link (must end with a ".csv") so I can't take the liberty of just doing a "pandas.read_csv".

I've tried using requests to download it but it seems like there's no content (content-length is 0):
[image: requests output]

Any help would be appreciated here..

Comment: _I'm aware that this is not an explicit csv link (must end with a ".csv")_  Of course it does.  The file is called `calendar_statement.csv`.  Have you even tried it?

Comment: There's nothing in that CSV download even when you open it in excel. 
This is not a python issue.

Comment: @TimRoberts , Yes, i've tried it. pd.read_csv(url) gives a EmptyDataError

Comment: @Slakker . Seems like python doesn't show any data but when i manually click on the link and download the file, there is data inside.

Comment: `wget` also gets an empty file with this URL.  Are you sure that URL is right?  How did you generate it?

Comment: You have to log in to this site, don't you?  Have you created a session so you can login?

Comment: @TimRoberts , ah i did not... 

i just tried 
`r = requests.get('https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?&start=1970-1-1%200:0&end=1970-4-1%200:0&filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&show=show&type=cal&bubble=true&calPeriod=-1', data = {'loginEmail': `email`, 'loginPassword': `password`})`

i did the above and the content length is still 0

Comment: Is that how they handle logins?  Are you sure?